A inexplicable EJBTransactionRolledbackException when EJB3.2 invoke using TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW in weblogic14
I has 3 stateless bean ScheduleTest,FacadeEjb,RunEjb! ScheduleTest.class is a schedule ejb to execute runSchedule method every 10 minutes,this class actually call the ejb FacadeEjb to do the job. in this class,Method runSecond has add annotation "TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW".when application run, i got a EJBTransactionRolledbackException at ScheduleTest.runSchedule. i don't understand why ,so add some logger in backend.
the backend logger print here:
Before Run--EJBContext.getRollbackOnly:false
FacadeEjb.runSecond catch a Exception!
I will contine to run...........
After Run--EJBContext.getRollbackOnly:true
ScheduleTest.runSchedule catch a Exception
So,i really confused! As I understand it,when run runSecond,system will create a new Transaction to execute  the job,and then ,it get a EJBExcption .even though this New Transaction will be rollback,but the orig transaction(the method "run" use) still be OK. unfortunately,the whole EJBContext.RollbackOnly flag has set to True,Why?
another incredible thing is--when  ScheduleTest.runSchedule run,i will catch a exception if add any jpa code!when remove jpa code,no exception i can catch
My Env:   EJB3.2      WebLogic 14.1.0
ScheduleTest
@Stateless
public class ScheduleTest {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ScheduleTest.class.getName());

@EJB
FacadeEjb ejb;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MesEngFilePathPU")
EntityManager mesEm;

@Schedule(minute = "1/10" , hour = "\*" , persistent = false)
public void runSchedule() {
try {
    ejb.run();
   //if i add a JPA Action,i will catch a exception,if i remove the following 2 line code,No exception will catch
    Query query = mesEm.createNativeQuery("declare v varchar2(1); begin select '1' into v from dual;end;");
    query.executeUpdate();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warning("ScheduleTest.runSchedule catch a Exception");
  }
  }
}  
    

class FacadeEjb
@Stateless
public class FacadeEjb {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FacadeEjb.class.getName());

    @EJB
    RunEjb ejb;
    
    @Resource
    SessionContext context;
    
    public void run() {
        logger.warning(String.format("Before Run--EJBContext.getRollbackOnly:%s" , context.getRollbackOnly()));
        runSecond();
        logger.warning(String.format("After Run--EJBContext.getRollbackOnly:%s" , context.getRollbackOnly()));
    }
    
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void runSecond() {
        try {
            ejb.getTestName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warning("FacadeEjb.runSecond catch a Exception!");
        }
        logger.warning("I will contine to run...........");
    }

}  
    

-------------------------class RunEjb
@Stateless
public class RunEjb {

    public String getTestName() {
        throw new EJBException("I throw a EJBException in RunEjb");
    }

}  
    

